# Teenage boy in space with a female robot?

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I don’t remember much about this book, as I read it years ago (around 2015 or so) in an intermediate school library, but it’s about a teenage boy traveling space with a female robot. I only remember one scene, and that’s when he goes in the spaceship he leans over and pukes. I remember that humans have space bases and shops and stuff. I think he gets into a fight with people with knives at one point, but I am not sure. Does anyone know the name of this book?

Comment: I would add the identification tag and an estimate of what year you think you read this book to give people a time frame.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking story-id questions to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.